# Understanding isomorphism of Hom's

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

During some reading I came across the statement 
$$Hom_R(M,N) \otimes R/I \cong Hom_{R/I}(M/IM,N/IN) $$ 
where $M,N$ are $R$-modules and $I$ an ideal of the commutative ring $R$. This is proved, under some assumptions on the modules. But my problem is that I don't really understand the statement. These Hom's are isomorphic - as what? $R$-modules? How does it make sense? And if it does, why is it not obvious?

Comment: If $M$ and $N$ are $R$-modules, there is a natural $R$-module structure on $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)$. Further, $R/I$ is also an $R$-module, and so $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N)\otimes_R R/I$ is an $R$-module. So yes, the isomorphism is as $R$-modules.

Comment: @walkar I agree with you that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,N) \otimes_R R/I$ is an $R$-module. But why is $\operatorname{Hom}_{R/I}(M/IM,N/IN)$ so?

Comment: Let $f: M/IM \rightarrow N/IN$ be an $R/I$-module homomorphism. Can you think of a natural action of $R$ on $f$? I.e., let $r \in R$. What would be the most natural thing for $r\cdot f(\overline{m})$ to be for some $\overline{m} \in M/IM$?

Comment: @walkar Yes ok, we can lift $f$ to be an $R$-module homomorphism. It is well defined since, for $x \in I$ we have $x \cdot f(\bar{m}) = f(x \bar{m})=f(0)=0$.